# Orchard CMS - Sudden 404 during development

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I was getting close to completing my first site using Orchard CMS, and when I went to enable the 'blog' module I saw an error page. I wish I had paid more attention to it, instead I closed it and restarted my site.

Now, I get 404 errors and I can access the front or back end of my site. I'm at a loss.

I found these in the error logs but I really don't know where to go from here...

2014-01-01 19:58:09,140 [11] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - A tenant could not be started: Default
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'Orchard.Blogs.Routing.ArchiveConstraint' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Orchard.Autoroute.Services.IPathResolutionService pathResolutionService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.Autoroute.Services.IPathResolutionService)'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 118
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b_*0() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 270
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 119
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\AutowiringParameter.cs:line 62
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ConstructorParameterBinding.cs:line 114
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 122
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.<Execute>b__0() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 270
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 119
   at Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.<>c*_DisplayClass4.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_1(IComponentRegistration cr) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Features\Collections\CollectionRegistrationSource.cs:line 75
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Features\Collections\CollectionRegistrationSource.cs:line 75
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 68
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 119
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Registration\ExternalRegistrySource.cs:line 80
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 68
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 119
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\AutowiringParameter.cs:line 62
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ConstructorParameterBinding.cs:line 114
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 122
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__0() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 270
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 119
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Registration\ExternalRegistrySource.cs:line 80
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 68
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 85
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 232
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 736
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 343
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 197
   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings) in d:\Builds\OrchardFull\src\Orchard\Environment\ShellBuilders\ShellContextFactory.cs:line 78
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings) in d:\Builds\Or

Comment: The site can't start, probably because you have an Orchard core and blog module that are out of sync. Make sure you use the version of the module that comes with Orchard.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I'm experiencing this same error when trying to upgrade a site. I have downloaded the sourcecode, changed over the connection string to point to my existing sites database and I get the error. I change it back and it works

Comment: Maybe old version pointing at a more recent DB?

Answer (score 0):

Grant all users NTFS write permission on the Orchard.Web folder. This might help -- I had a similar error when permissions were not set.
Also, make sure that AppPool user (or Network service - if that's who owns your application pool) is dbo in the database that you are connecting to.
AppPool user name is "IIS AppPool\" -- you add this user as windows user in SQL server, and then user/role mapping give him dbo permissions for required database.